# Server Side Caching With Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Below I have a basic dash app where I query some data in a database and put it in a store component on the server. I am scratching my head on how to update the data store on a set interval (server side). In the current configuration below, it updates using the dcc.Interval. When multiple clients are connected, each person triggers their own interval component which very quickly deadlocks the database. What would be the best way to go about triggering the function that outputs the store on a set “server side” interval? I have been using [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/show-and-tell-server-side-caching/42854) article as inspiration, but can’t seem to fully wrap my head around how to adapt it.

edit: I have looked in to [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but am unsure how to use this with dcc.Store. This seems to be the best way to go about this (if it is possible).

Any help would be awesome!

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Query data", id="btn"),dcc.Graph(id='Time-graph',style={'width': '100%', 'height': '900px'}),
    dcc.Store(id="store",storage_type="session"),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component-Time',
        interval=1 * 8000,  # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    )

])

# Create (server side) cache. Works with any flask caching backend.
cc = CallbackCache(cache=FileSystemCache(cache_dir="../cache"))


@cc.cached_callback(Output("store", "data"), [Trigger("interval-component-Time", "n_intervals")])  # Trigger is like Input, but excluded from args
def query_data():
    channel = pyodbc.connect("...connection string...'")
    Run=pd.read_sql("command ", channel).iloc[0]['Name']
    Event=pd.read_sql("command ", channel).iloc[0]['EventId']
    Lap=pd.read_sql("command ", channel)
    groups = [Run, Event, Lap]
    return groups

@cc.callback(Output("Time-graph", "figure"), [Input("store", "data")])
def update_graph(data):

    ...code to generate figure...

    return fig

cc.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: hi I found a similar question here https://community.plotly.com/t/solved-updating-server-side-app-data-on-a-schedule/6612/2

basically, you create a different ThreadPoolExecutor for the update

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-redis-celery-periodic-updates/) is a multithreaded solution on Github based on Redis and Celery.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you place your database calls in a function decorated with a time based cache (such as `@cache.memoize(timeout=TIMEOUT)` from [`flask-caching`](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). See the second example on https://dash.plotly.com/performance.

This will ensure that all users hit the cached data from the database, regardless of the number of intervals that user has been waiting for. It will only refresh once the timer for the cache has expired, so it won't endlessly refresh in the background.

Comment: Wouldn't this still have everyone calling to update the cache instead of the cache updating on its own at a set interval?

Comment: Users wouldn't be explicitly calling to update the cache, they would be calling to fetch data from the database. However they would instead hit the cache as long as the cache hasn't expired. Once it expires, the next request then updates from the database and resets the TTL on the cache.

Comment: Ah understood. Trying to apply the knowledge from that article to my example and just can't get anything to trigger properly, or share data between callbacks

Comment: the error I run in to `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`